# Editing Microsoft Word Documents Programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I want to know if this could be done.

I am building a data dictionary for our software system (school project), and I'm thinking of an automated way to do this. Basically I don't use much of Microsoft Word (2007), I only use it in documenting schools stuff, etc. I want to know if its possible to create/edit a Word document programmatically from a template.

The idea is, I will create a page on Word that contains an empty form that will be repeated on every page. For every data that I will input to my program, it will update the corresponding field in the form and skips to the next form.

The purpose of this, is to eliminate copy-paste methods (my habit) and to speed things up when doing the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Word automation, as suggested by others, will lead you to a world of hurt for two major reasons:

1. Office is not intended to be run unattended, so it can pop up message boxes at any time, and
2. It is (probably) not licensed to enable office functionality for computers which don't have it. If you generate a Word document on a web site using automation, you have to make sure that this functionality cannot be reached by computers which don't have office installed (unless they changed this rule in the last years).

I have used [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com), it costs a little, but it works well and is intended for this.

Comment: I won't comment on your suggestion since I know nothing about it, but regarding your reasons for avoiding office automation I'd say that I can't remember having any issues with number 1 after the code had been written properly, and number 2 might not be relevant for the OP since he doesn't mention a webserver. Though I'll give you that it can be difficult to write automation code correctly, but I think your answer is overly negative.

Comment: Also, even if $899 might not be that much money when developing professional software, when doing a project in school it might be a bit excessive :)

Comment: @ho1: School projects are typically funnier than creating a Word document. Document creation seems like a typical business project.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly sure what you really want, but creating word documents with c# shouldn't be any problem:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316384

Answer (score 4):

If i find out your purpose correctly you need to visit this microsoft msdn link

[Manipulating Word 2007 Files with OpenXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb656295.aspx#Y593)

Comment: Yes, Open XML is the way!

Answer (score 2):

Definitely possible. A fairly easy way of doing it using Office Automation. See this KB article for a basic sample: [How to automate Microsoft Word to create a new document by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316384)

I think the main difference to that sample will be that you'll open your template and do `SaveAs` instead of creating a new document, but I can't remember exactly.

However, depending on your exact requirements, there might be better alternatives. For example, it's not recommended to do Office Automation on servers (including on webservers), so if that's needed you might want to look at something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use com interop of .net framework.

[Understanding the Word Object Model from a .NET Developer's Perspective](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192495%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

[Building COM Objects in C#](http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/01/com-interoperability-in-net-framework-part-i/)

Answer (score 0):

Using COM programming is not the best way as mentioned by erikkallen, I suggest using OPEN XML. It is really easy to use and your document generation operation will be very fast.

http://blog.goyello.com/2009/08/21/how-to-generate-open-xml-file-in-c-in-4-minutes/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205(v=office.12).aspx