# Modify existing word files and save in c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am developing business website, which has requirement like

- Customer enters his personal details on web form
- Client has provided predefined word template
- Open template file programmatically & Insert data into that word file (in specific position only) and print it

Template could be like (just a sample)

```
Full Name   : _________________________  
Middle Name : _____________________   
Last Name : _______________________
```

My questions

1. Is it possible to do this ? If yes Which library to use ?
2. Is it legal to place that library on web server which does not have microsoft office license ?

Reference :

[Editing Microsoft Word Documents Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955520/editing-microsoft-word-documents-programmatically)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb656295.aspx#Y593

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A previous question [I want to open an excel file and wait for user to edit and save it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865738/i-want-to-open-an-excel-file-and-wait-for-user-to-edit-and-save-it/23873929#23873929) dealt with a similar issue (althogh for a front end program). The library being used is a microsft produced open source library for manipulating OpenXML format (DocX, XlsX) files so is suitable for search and replace operations without licence costs.

The one thing it wont do is print, however if you return the byte stream as a Word mime type, the user can print the document themselves, but only if they have a copy of Word or other application which can read DocX format documents. Perhaps a better solution would be to convert the Document you mailmerge into PDF before sending back to the browser ?

Comment: No its not the same ! I am not showing word file to user to save instead my web app will automatically fill his details and then generate new word file

Comment: Its a similar issue; you want to know what library you can use to manipulate Office format files and the license impacts of this. I'd recommend using the indicated library on your server to generate the DocX file, however printing of an Office format document requires an Office application installation.